# Will my baggage be checked through to the destination by Lufthansa?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, transit-visas, check-in, lufthansa

I reserved flights from Hong Kong to Dublin and will change planes at Munich, and when I return from Dublin to Hong Kong I will change planes at Frankfurt. All legs are operated by Lufthansa. I am just wondering if Lufthansa will check my baggage through to the destination, because if they don't do so, I will have to apply for a airport transit visa.

Comment: While dropping your luggage at the baggage drop counter mention it to them, they will do it.

Comment: Note that if you need to collect luggage an airside transport visa will not be sufficient. You would need a regular visitor visa.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your both legs are on the same ticket (made in the same booking) then they will definitely check in your luggage to the final destination. You will just change planes without going through immigration.

If you have two separate bookings than it is not as obvious - contact the airline to double check.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, since you are using the same company, if you have one reservation number for both legs, then you should be fine. Your luggage should be going through without the need to pick them up and check them in again during the transit.

Comment: So that means I will stay in the international transit area in Munich and Frankfurt?

Comment: @BrianYang Yes, that's how it's intended to work, certainly when you book it all on Lufthansa (low-cost airlines, separate tickets, etc. can create complications but that's moot here). (+1 to the answer)

Comment: Minor nit-pick: it doesn't matter if it's the same air line or not. It matters if all legs of the flight are on a single booking and have the same ticket number. If it's two bookings you will have to re-check even if both bookings are on Lufthansa. That's most likely the case here, but it's worth making sure.

Comment: @Hilmar Isn't that what "if you have one reservation number for both legs" mean? And it kind of matters that's it's on the same airlines in that you don't have to worry about interlining agreement and other niceties… It's not impossible to find exceptions but it makes sense to point out that booking it all at once from the same airlines through their hubs all but guarantees it will work.

Comment: Also, isn't the opposite actually possible? I.e. two separate bookings, but ask for the luggage to be checked through to the final destination? Quite often when I check-in (especially for long haul flights) they ask if the destination of my flight is "my final destination" (when they obviously have all the information about the booking that includes the current flight), so I suppose they would be able to accommodate a consecutive separate booking (as long as the connection time etc. are fine).

Comment: @jcaron You can always ask, but there's no guarantee they can accommodate you if you have separate bookings. Many airlines will not. The system isn't really built for that and not all airlines have interline agreements (and even if they do, those agreements may have restrictions we're not privy to). They ask so both you and the agent are sure you're on the same page about where the bags are going (it can get confusing if you have a long layover where you may or may not want the bags in between), but that doesn't mean they'll accommodate separate bookings.